# fetch offsetTop of element with respect to another element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to calculate the scrolled distance of a div element within another div element. I am using offsetTop for that, but it always returns 0 in my code. I am unable to figure out where I am making the mistake.

```js
function getScrollVal() {
 console.log(window.pageYOffset);
 var wrap = document.getElementById("wrapper");
 console.log(wrap.id);
 console.log(wrap.offsetParent.id);
 var parent = wrap.offsetParent;
    console.log("scrollTop: " + wrap.scrollTop + " scrollLeft: " + wrap.scrollLeft);
 console.log("offsetTop: " + wrap.offsetTop + " offsetLeft: " + wrap.offsetLeft);
  /*
  var xx = wrap.offsetLeft;
 var yy = wrap.offsetTop;
 while(wrap = wrap.offsetParent){
  xx += wrap.offsetLeft;
  yy += wrap.offsetTop;
 }
  */
 }
```

```css
body, html {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

#contain {
 position: relative;
 width:100%;
 height: 100vh;
 background: yellow;
 overflow: auto;
}
#wrapper {
 width: 85%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 background: red;
}
.full {
 height: 100vh;
 width: 85%;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
#one { background:#222;}
#two{ background:#00c590;}
#three{ background:#3429c5;}
#four{background:#bbb;}
#b {
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 1000;
 top: 30px;
 left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="contain">
    <div id="wrapper">
   <div id="one" class="full"></div>
   <div id="two" class="full"></div>
   <div id="three" class="full"></div>
   <div id="four" class="full"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
 <button id="b" type="button" onClick="getScrollVal();" value="click me">Press me</button>
 
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried the js code inside the comment. That one is not providing a fruitful result. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the element `#contain` is the overflow element, you can try get the scrollTop like this:

```
console.log("scroll top:", document.getElementById('contain').scrollTop);
```

From MDN:

> An element's scrollTop is a measurement of the distance of **an element's top to its topmost visible content**. [Element.scrollTop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop)